# Avoid calling mvc action method calling twice when in AngulrJs routing

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I will explain the problem  now in detail.I have to pass some parameters or object using $http method in controller to MVC Action method Three.but here when I click Route Three link the action method Three in Home Controller is calling twice as first  is for templateUrl and then for controller's $http method .Here I want to call the controller first then the view(templateUrl) should load .Please let me know the solution

The Angular code :

```
    app.controller('routeparamtest', function($scope, $routeParams,$http) {  
        $http({
            url: "/Home/three",
            method: "GET",
            params: { id:20}
        });

    });


    var configFunction = function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.

            .when('/routeThree', {
                templateUrl: 'Home/Three',
                controller: 'routeparamtest'
            });
    }
```

The MVC Controller Code :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Three(int id = 1)
    {
            return View();
    }
}
```

The HTML Code :

```
 <ul>
      <li><a href="#/routeThree" > Route Three</a></li> 
    </ul>  <div ng-view>
```

The Three.cshtml code :

```
some html code goes here
```

Comment: Can you please try by removing these line
 $http({
            url: "/Home/three",
            method: "GET",
            params: { id:20}
        });
From your controller routeparamtest

Comment: what if I want pass more than one parameter or an object.How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass multiple parameters then you just need to create an object as following.

```
var data = [{
        Id: "1",
        Value: "apple"
    },
    {
        Id: "2",
        Value: "banana"
    }];
```

And pass it in anuglarjs call as following.

```
this.doSth = function(data){
    var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "Home/DoSth",
        data: data
        //or data: JSON.stringify(data) ??
        });
    return response;
};
```

To get data in MVC Controller just Create a class

```
public class  MyClass
{
  public int Id { get; set;}
  public string Value { get; set;}
}
```

use the list in your method

```
public string DoSth(List<MyClass> data)
{
    //access your data
    //data[0].Id,data[0].Value or by any other way
}
```

Hope this will help you.
thanks

Comment: The problem with my code is the HomeController's Three method is calling twice First is for
 templateUrl:  templateUrl: 'Home/Three' and secod time for the angularjs controller routeparamtest . How can we avoid the first time calling since I want to pass some more parameters or may be an object type